# Are unit tests and continuous integration part of web app delivery?

Tags: web-development

I offer high quality fast web app prototyping services. As part of the interview process, the client, a non technical bootstrap founder brought in a backend developer/consultant to ask me questions about deployment pipeline, test coverage, CI and other infra related topics. My previous clients have never asked about those. Is it common to include testing and CI as part of web app delivery?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has no specifics related to freelancing. This question is about general software project management, so it may fit at [softwareengineering.se]

Answer (score 2):

It is not common but if client ask for it than you can offer him CI and testing for additional charges

Comment: Welcome to Freelancing! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, it would be preferable to back it with references to credible sources and/or academic research. Unbacked posts attract downvotes and disputes.

Comment: Thanks for that, I would do that from next time.